# Insert data only in even cells in a table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I populate only even cells with values from an Array and insert single element in every odd cell ?

```
//I have an Array with following values :
let Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//And HTML Element :
let Element = "<span> Some Element </span>"

// I create a table with cells = length of elements * 2
let newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.id = "tableID";
let row = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Array.length * 2; i++) {
   row[i] = newTable.insertRow(i);
}
```

How can I populate the table even cells - 0 2 4 6 8 with the numbers from the Array and put the HTMLElement in between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check wether or not you are even (i % 2 === 0 ) will do that, and then decide what you wish to add

```js
//I have an Array with following values :
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//And HTML Element :
let element = "<span> Some Element </span>";

// I create a table with cells = length of elements * 2
let newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.id = "tableID";
let row = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length * 2; i++) {
  row[i] = newTable.insertRow();
  let cell = row[i].insertCell();
   if (i%2 === 0) {
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode( array[i/2] ) );
   } else {
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode( element ) );
   }
}

document.getElementById('container').appendChild( newTable );
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I'm marking your post as answer as the array[i/2] was the key in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

This code is intentionally very similar to yours, it just adds a cell to each row and then modifies the cell's content according to the condition `i%2`:

```js
//I have an Array with following values : 
let Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//And HTML Element :
let Element = "<span> Some Element </span>"

// I create a table with cells = length of elements * 2 
let newTable = document.createElement("table");
newTable.id = "tableID";
document.body.appendChild(newTable);

let row = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Array.length * 2; i++) {
  row[i] = newTable.insertRow(-1).insertCell(0);
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    row[i].innerHTML = i;
  else
    row[i].innerHTML = Element;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, its possible to do:

```
let j=0;
for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
   row[j++] = newTable.insertRow(i);
   row[j++] = newTable.insertRow(Element);
}
```